# PHP how to move the children up to each parent

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been stuck on this for a while now, internet has helped but I can't get it right.  I have an array listed below and I've been trying to create a new array from this one with the children in each odd number moved up to the corresponding parent.  I came close with a $new array and a counter checking if the index was odd or even and then if the odd number is true reassign the children to the current parent.

Here's the array.

```
Array
(
   [0] => hair-and-beauty
   [1] => Array
    (
        [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
        [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
        [_business_price_0] => 22
        [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
        [_business_price_1] => 55
        [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
        [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
        [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
        [0] => 
    )

   [2] => hair-colouring
   [3] => Array
      (
        [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
        [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
        [_business_price_0] => 22
        [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
        [_business_price_1] => 55
        [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
        [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
        [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
        [0] => 
    )

   [4] => hair-styling
   [5] => Array
      (
        [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
        [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
        [_business_price_0] => 22
        [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
        [_business_price_1] => 55
        [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
        [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
        [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
        [0] => 
    )

)
```

I need to get the kids like this.

```
 Array
  (
       [0] => hair-and-beauty  => Array
         (
            [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
            [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
            [_business_price_0] => 22
            [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
            [_business_price_1] => 55
            [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
            [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
            [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
          )

     [1] => hair-colouring => Array
          (
            [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
            [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
            [_business_price_0] => 22
            [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
            [_business_price_1] => 55
            [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
            [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
            [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
          )

        [2] => hair-styling  => Array
           (
            [_business_title_0] => Hair Colouring One
            [_business_description_0] => Hair Colouring Desc
            [_business_price_0] => 22
            [_business_image_id_1] => 2351
            [_business_price_1] => 55
            [_business_description_1] => Hair Styling Desc
            [_business_title_1] => Hair Styling
            [_business_image_id_0] => 2366
          )

     )
```

My php code isn't working out right for me :(

```
    $new = array();
    $number = 0;
     foreach($menu as $current){
         //If number is even
         if ($number % 2 == 0) {
            array_push($new[$current]); 
        }else{
            //number isnt even so go for children and add them to parent
            $new[$value['index']] = $current;
        }
        ++$number; 
     }
     unset($menu);
    usort($new);

    $x = $new;
    $json=$x;
```

The main array is called $menu.

Any help appreciated.

I'm steering in the direction of an array_merge

Var export :

```
array (
  0 => 'hair-and-beauty',
  1 => 
  array (
    '_business_title_0' => 'Hair Colouring One',
    '_business_description_0' => 'Hair Colouring Desc',
    '_business_price_0' => '22',
    '_business_image_id_1' => '2351',
    '_business_price_1' => '55',
    '_business_description_1' => 'Hair Styling Desc',
    '_business_title_1' => 'Hair Styling',
    '_business_image_id_0' => '2366',
    0 => NULL,
  ),
  2 => 'hair-colouring',
  3 => 
  array (
    '_business_title_0' => 'Hair Colouring One',
    '_business_description_0' => 'Hair Colouring Desc',
    '_business_price_0' => '22',
    '_business_image_id_1' => '2351',
    '_business_price_1' => '55',
    '_business_description_1' => 'Hair Styling Desc',
    '_business_title_1' => 'Hair Styling',
    '_business_image_id_0' => '2366',
    0 => NULL,
  ),
  4 => 'hair-styling',
  5 => 
  array (
    '_business_title_0' => 'Hair Colouring One',
    '_business_description_0' => 'Hair Colouring Desc',
    '_business_price_0' => '22',
    '_business_image_id_1' => '2351',
    '_business_price_1' => '55',
    '_business_description_1' => 'Hair Styling Desc',
    '_business_title_1' => 'Hair Styling',
    '_business_image_id_0' => '2366',
    0 => NULL,
  ),
)null
```

Comment: Sorry there was before I edited it I'll remove it, it's because I then convert it to json

Comment: I would look at how you create the array and do it properly there rather than trying to fudge it into what you want it to be after it is wrong to start with

Comment: You want to take every even entry and make it a child of the previous odd entry? (If you use var_export() on your data and update your post we can copy and paste it.)

Comment: I've redone the initial creation a few times and come into the same problem that's why I'm kind of fudging the result.  I think it will be easier to alter the $menu result afterwards as it pulls from 3 tables in the DB and that in itself was problematic due to the relationships in the table being set up incorrectly by a previous coder.

Comment: @mkaatman adding the dump now, I want the value in the odd numbers to become nested children of the previous parent.

Comment: The expected "output" is ambiguous. What are the expected keys? I guess the strings.

Comment: The keys would be : hair-and-beauty, hair-colouring, hair-styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `$input` be the array posted in the question.

This simple piece of code does the job:

```
$output = array();
foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as $i) {
    $output[$i[0]] = array_filter($i[1]);
}
```

The calls to [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) remove the empty entries from the arrays on even positions (the new children). Its purpose is to remove the key `0` from them (it is not present in the expected output) but it also removes other keys whose values are equivalent to [`FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

If you want to keep all the string keys and get rid only of `0` then you can write it as:

```
$output = array();
foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as $i) {
    unset($i[1][0]);
    $output[$i[0]] = $i[1];
}
```

If you use [PHP 5.5 or newer](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.foreach-list) you can write it nicer:

```
$output = array();
foreach (array_chunk($input, 2) as list($k, $v)) {
    unset($v[0]);
    $output[$k] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
$num_pairs = count($old) / 2;
$new = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $num_pairs; $i++) {
  $new[] = [$old[$i*2] => $old[$i*2+1]];
}
```

If you want the resulting array, to be associative though (as one of your comments suggests), you could use this instead:

```
$num_pairs = count($old) / 2;
$new = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $num_pairs; $i++) {
  $new[$old[$i*2]] = $old[$i*2+1];
}
```